# Why is "Is converting to Islam easier than Judaism?" being voted as off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

The question [Is converting to Islam easier than Judaism?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40135/17163) has now received four close votes, and I'm wondering why:

**Question**: Why is "Is converting to Islam easier than Judaism?" being voted as off topic?

It doesn't seem to be a clear-cut case to me, so it seems like something we should establish on meta.

It's a comparative religion question.  I made an argument here as to why I think such questions should be on topic: [Are comparative studies on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/917/17163)  If we're going to vote to close comparative religion questions, we should have a tangible reason for doing so, i.e.,

> "This is off-topic because X, Y, and Z, as discussed here: [link to meta thread]."

not

> "This is off-topic because I feel it's off topic."

I get the feeling that maybe the votes are due to it being half off-topic, by being half about Judaism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparative religions, comparative sects, and comparative *fiqh* are topics that are widely taught, and have often been the focus of many scholars in the past and present. However, said topics always pose a very high risk of ending up in controversy, at best. See [Is Allah not omnipresent?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40133/) as a recent example, and [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/) from five years ago.

The way it seems to me is that Islam.SE tries to avoid comparative <*topics*> due to the risk involved in causing division, and the assumption that an expert on Islam is not necessarily an expert on other religions (which is valid, but is somewhat fallaciously interpreted as true, as in an expert on Islam is definitely not an expert on other religions). This, as answered in [Are comparative studies on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/917/), does not address why Islam.SE shies away from comparative *fiqh* or comparative sects topics.

I am personally not opposed to having comparative <*topics*> in general, provided it is clear what the boundaries are.